Comparison Bar Chart in PowerBI
I want to create a comparison bar chart on powerBI desktop. Since I have a dataset with columns "Subject Names", "Previous Grade", "Current Grade", "Previous GPA", and "Current GPA". I want to compare the counts of "Previous Grade" and "Current Grade" according to the grade label. i.e x-axis will be grades and the Y-axis will show the counts just like the image below:

I have created a measure of total counts and a column with grade labels (i.e. A+, A, A-, B, etc).
It'll be my pleasure if you help me to complete my task. Thank You so much.
